Reading ACR122U NFC tag via JS in the browser
I'm using an ACR122U NTC tag USB reader. I need to get data in to the console. Is this possible?
I tried navigator.serial.requestPort, navigator.usb.getDevice, request device, everything, but no compatible devices ae showing
I have connected my NFC reader in the USB port and it's showing in device manager of Windows and my browser has all permissions set.

Does this help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_NFC_API?

The most important part of that link above is the 'Browser compatibility' table - this is only currently supported on mobile devices, and even then it's patchy.
